# Relativistic ray tracing and spheric texture

Tags: c++, rendering, gpu

## Question

I need some advice on which techniques and programming environment to use for my specific problem.

### The Problem

Given a heavy object in space with a static surface above it´s Schwarzschild radius, how would someone positioned in space see it´s surface (illumination is ignored)? One might imagne a neutron star for example
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star, my program should result in a picture similiar to (but more detailed than) the picture on the site.

Note that the program should be capeable of rendering several frames per second and free view and movement "like" in a FPS.

I want to solve this problem with ray tracing in the NON-Euclidean relativistic space.
To do this, I need to solve ~1000 independend differential equations, which determine, where a ray would hit the surface.

The ODE is u´´+ u = 3Ru^2/2 with initial condition for u and u´, R is constant. It terminates once u leaves a defined bound. So solving this wont be too complicated.

After that I would do some routines for each pixel:

- Transform to spere coordinates with respect to some direction (no if branches)
- Apply some special relativistic angle correction (possibly some easy function without branching)
- Transform one part of the angle to the angle on the surface by applying the interpolated function defined by the differential equations. The pixels that don´t hit the surface should be black now.
- Transforming the angles back to some canonical sphere coordinates (no branching).
- Not sure about this point: For the surface graphics a sperical Delaunay triangulation has been initially calculated and for each ray the colour is determined by weighting the colours of the corresponding triangles corners. But I would be glad if someone came up with a better idea.

I would appreciate in a C/C++/C# like environment

### Questions:

- What framework would be suitable for my problem?
  open GL appears to be focused on euclidean ray tracing, which is useless in this setup.
  CUDA would restrict me to Nvidea gpus
  Could open cl be the right thing?
- Are the operations described executeable on the GPU?
  I´m especially worried about accesing the interpolated function data in parallel from the various processors. Also locating (O(log(#vertices) and branching) a lot of rays in parallel on the Delaunay trianglulation seems like a problem for me. **open question**
- Do you have better ideas for representing a graphic on a surface and deciding what colour a certain position should have?
- Could it be worth the trouble to calculate the differnetial equations on the GPU? They are solved by runge kutta methods and terminate after arbitrary times.

### About my level of knowledge:

I´m a student of mathematics and the problems above are involved in my Bac. theses.
I have some experience with C++ and already learned about GUIs in C# and Gtk. Coding is not my everyday activity, but I don´t have troubles with the standard stuff.
Once my theses is finished, I will share the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions with respect to the presented problem:

This is very good that your ODEs are independent (suitable for parallel execution) and that you can use fixed-step integration (no thread divergence), because this makes your problem very suitable for GPU.

One of the libraries that may be helpful here is boost::odeint, which provides implementations of the most popular ODEs integrators (Runge-Kutta included). It also supports GPU accelerated computations, however in this case you have to use device_vector as your state type and you have to use thrust::for_each transformation as your equation (which may be difficult to achieve in your case). It seems that thrust libraries support not only Nvidia GPUs, but I am not sure.

If thrust library functions are not suitable for your problem, you may provide your own Runge-Kutta implementation (not very complicated anyway) and your ODEs definitions using CUDA or OpenCL. If you decide to use CUDA, and you are able to use device with compute capability 3.5 or higher, you can take advantage of so called "dynamic parallelism", which allows you to call kernel function (in CUDA, this is a function that runs on GPU) from another kernel function, that effectively allows you to create some threads from the other thread. You can for example call RungeKutta method with 5 threads (5-point Runge-Kutta) and from each thread you can call 1000 threads for your ODE calculation (each thread computes one equation). Modern GPUs usually have over 10 SM (streaming multiprocessor) and each SM is able to handle 2048 threads, so you can probably perform each integration step with just one calculation split over 5000 threads. I am not sure about this capability if you decide to use OpenCL.

Your next steps (coordinates transformation, etc.) look quite suitable for thrust::for_each function, however if it turns out that they are not, you can use CUDA/OpenCL interface again.

As for final graphical representation, I can't give you any advice, but I suppose that you can simply use any graphical library (including OpenGL) and just put pixels in their places manually.

Finally, in your project time performance is very important. Remember to use some profiler (for example Nvidia visual profiler) to investigate your code and find out which part is the slowest. You should also write unit tests, not only to test your code for potential bugs, but also to test the performance of each part of your project separately.

You can do this in C++ of course.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer:

Comment: I will surely look into this library and I´m glad that parallelistation of the pixel routines is granted.
The ODEs are rather simple (1D/2D, first order and pretty smooth) so I think  it would already be a big boost to solve each them and standard implemented Runge Kutta will work fine.

So do you think that reading one datastructure (transformation function, and Delaunay triangulation) in parallel from the GPU works?

(I was trolled by hitting enter and not shift+enter)

Comment: With odeint it looks like I could even solve the equations for each pixel and not just in the equatorial plane. That could be used for rotating black holes :).

Comment: As long as you use Map or Gather (not Scatter) operations (refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874612/cuda-scatter-communication-pattern) you are able to do it concurrently on GPU without any additional hacks. I suppose that Delaunay triangulation is that kind of algorithm (concrete output depends on multiple inputs), but since I did not implement it, I can't be sure. Let me know, when you finish your project, I am curious about possible results.